# Parsing from string to float32 yields incorrect results, f#

Tags: c#, .net, f#

Im trying to parse strings of coordinates using System.Single.Parse, but when the numbers are too low odd thing occur.
Example:

```
System.Single.Parse " 0.0001";;  
val it : float32 = 9.99999975e-05f
```

Comment: `|> printfn "%f"` will print what you expect.